# React Apollo using Named Variable

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo

Im trying to export a named gql query to be used in another react component in order to call it to update the apollo cache. The code works if I use PRODUCTS_QUERY since I export const PRODUCTS_QUERY. However, I would prefer to use the named gql variable 'productsQuery' for better naming convention. However, when I use 'productsQuery' in place of PRODUCTS_QUERY, it will throw an error. Anyone has successfully used the named variable? Please advise. Thanks in advance

In Home.js

```
export const PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    products {
      id
      price
      pictureUrl
      name
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(PRODUCTS_QUERY, { name: "productsQuery" })(Home);
```

In AddProduct.js

```
// import { PRODUCTS_QUERY } from "./Home";
   import { productsQuery } from "./Home";

 try {
      let response = await this.props.mutate({
        variables: {
          name,
          price,
          picture
        },

//  - - - - - - - - THIS PART WORKS - - - - - - -
        // update: (store, { data: { createProduct } }) => {
        //   const data = store.readQuery({ query: PRODUCTS_QUERY });
        //   data.products.push(createProduct);
        //   store.writeQuery({ query: PRODUCTS_QUERY, data });
        // }

//  - - - - - - - - THIS PART FAILS - - - - - - -
        update: (store, { data: { createProduct } }) => {
          const data = store.readQuery({ query: productsQuery });
          data.products.push(createProduct);
          store.writeQuery({ query: productsQuery, data });
        }
      });
      console.log("RESPONSE", response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERROR", err);
    }

    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
  };
```

Any way I can export in a manner which allows me to use named variable 'productsQuery' rather than 'PRODUCTS_QUERY' since purpose of naming is to make naming convention standardized. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the error message. Also, is this the working code, or the code that doesn’t work?

Comment: Hi. Above codes work. However, i prefer to use named variable 'productsQuery' rather than 'PRODUCTS_QUERY' (which is seen in codes). Any idea how to use named variables for my gql query n mutation in my update store function?

Comment: If you post the code that doesn't work and the error message, it will be easier to figure out what is the problem. Otherwise, I can only guess.

Comment: Hi Tal Z, i have amended the source code to highlight the working codes and non-working codes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Home.js file you exported 2 things:

1. The query with the name `PRODUCTS_QUERY`
2. The graphql operation as the `default`

The way it is written now, you cannot import `{ productsQuery }` since you didn't export anything with that exact name.

The `name` option you set in your graphql operation
(`{ name: "productsQuery" }`) is not related to what you are describing. That option affects the prop name that the component will receive with the data from the query.

A few options to make it work:

- Rename `PRODUCTS_QUERY` to `productsQuery` in `Home.js` and use the same import.
- you can assign and export `productsQuery` instead of `PRODUCTS_QUERY` in your `Home.js`, like so:

  `export const productsQuery = PRODUCTS_QUERY;`
- If you don't want to change `Home.js`, you can change your import to something like:

  `import { PRODUCTS_QUERY: productsQuery } from "./Home";`

There are probably more ways to do that.

Comment: Thanks Tal Z! I got an error when I use import { PRODUCTS_QUERY: productsQuery } from "./Home";  I used { PRODUCTS_QUERY as productsQuery } from "./Home"; and it works fine.

Comment: For your second suggestion export const productsQuery = PRODUCTS_QUERY; not too sure how to implement it cause i still need to export default graphql(PRODUCTS_QUERY, { name: "productsQuery" })(Home); for it to work; otherwise will throw an error

Comment: Truth be told, i should just use the graphql compose function and use your first suggestion for the naming convention and that makes the codes less verbose and cleaner. Thanks a lot for your sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `as` to rename a non-default export.

```
import { PRODUCTS_QUERY as productsQuery } from "./Home";
```

The syntax for renaming imports is a little different than renaming an argument in other js cases, this **won't** work:

```
// Incorrect 
import { PRODUCTS_QUERY: productsQuery} from "./Home";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot stephen